# Initial selection for tablesorter filter w/ select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter, jquery-select2

Based on the [official example](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-select2.html) of **[tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/)** filtering with **[select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)**, I am trying to implement initial selection of options for filter and I'm stuck with **tablesorter** not updating filtered rows.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/5dUk9/1/.

Take a look at the first column, *xyz* values should be filtered out, but they're not.
If you do the manual selection though, it works as expected.

```
// ***
var filter = $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2( $cell, indx, {
    match : true, // adds "filter-match" to header
    cellText : 'Match: ',
    width: '85%',
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    }
});
filter.siblings("input.select2").select2("val", ["abc", "def"]);
return filter;
// ***
```

Two things unclear for me in this piece of code: whether `initSelection` is needed
in this scenario and how to notify **tablesorter** of changes if required so.

Of course, any other suggestion would be very helpful.

Original example *(without my changes)*: http://jsfiddle.net/5dUk9/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Mottie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145346/mottie) for quickly implementing this feature and providing a [demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/5dUk9/2/).

There is also a workaround I have found:

```
filter.siblings("input.select2").select2("val", ["abc", "def"], true);
```

Though it doesn't always work, then wrapping in `setTimeout()` should quick-and-dirty fix this: http://jsfiddle.net/5dUk9/3/.

Comment: Check out the "official" [demo in the documentation](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-select2.html)